# Why can't I reconstruct parameters of a synthetic data set?

Tags: logistic, python, scikit-learn

The following Python function creates synthetic binary labeled data that is supposed to perfectly follow the logistic regression model:

```
def generate_data(params, N, epsilon_std=.2):
    X = pd.DataFrame()
    X_p = pd.DataFrame()
    for ix in params.index:
        if ix == 'intercept':
            X[ix] = np.ones(N)
        else:
            X[ix] = np.random.rand(N)
        X_p[ix] = X[ix] * params[ix]

    X_p['__epsilon__'] = np.random.randn(N) * epsilon_std
    X_p['logit'] = X_p.sum(axis=1)
    X_p['label'] = X_p.logit > 0.0
    X['label'] = X_p['label']
    return X
```

The function above receives a vector of parameters (interecept and coefficients), generates random numbers, adds some noise, multiplies the parameters and the generated numbers to calculate the theoretical logit value and then assigns a label (positive if the logit is positive and negative, otherwise).

Now, generate the data, and use `sklearn` logistic regression model to calculate the parameters.

```
X = generate_data(params, 5000, epsilon_std=.1)
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X[params.index], X.label)
result = lr.coef_.ravel()
```

The problem is that, although the resulting model is accurate, the calculated parameters don't even resemble the theoretical ones.

The following code generates a lot of models and draws parameter histogram. The vertical lines represent parameter values that I expect to see:

```
params = pd.Series({'intercept': 0,
                   'x': -1.,
                   'y': 1.})
params = params
fit_values = []
for i in range(100):
    X = generate_data(params, 5000, epsilon_std=.5)
    lr = LogisticRegression()
    lr.fit(X[params.index], X.label)
    result = lr.coef_.ravel()
    result = result 
    fit_values.append(result)
fit_values = pd.DataFrame(fit_values, columns=params.index)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(params), figsize=(9, 2))
axes = axes.ravel()
for p, ax in zip(params.index, 
                     axes):
    ax.hist(fit_values[p], alpha=.3)
    ax.axvline(params[p])
    ax.set_title(p)
```

[image: parameter distribution]

I tried the same process using `statsmodels`. The result was the same.  What am I missing?

Comment: `X_p['label'] = X_p.logit > .5` doesn't seem to be assigning a label based on the sign of the logit: it is comparing it to $1/2$, not $0$! Regardless, this is not the underlying model for logistic regression. These two errors likely conspire to produce the strange results you report.

Comment: you are right, but even then, the parameters (not the intercept) look scaled.

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
for people to work with. This seems to be more of a statistical / conceptual question than a coding question, & is hence on topic here, but you haven't set the random seed, or provided specified parameter values, or displayed the erroneous results.

Comment: The data generating process that you are using is a Probit and not a Logit. Logit and Probit parameters are not directly comparable.

Comment: @Josef: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.